# configure php using pear on linux

Tags: php, linux, pear, lampp, proc-open

I have lampp installed on my linux box. I am trying to use proc_open as below.

```
    $spec = array(
            array("pty"), 
            array("pty"),
            array("pty")
    );

    $this->process = proc_open($command, $spec, $this->pipes);
```

But i am getting Warning: proc_open() [function.proc-open]: pty pseudo terminal is not support on this system in...

I found that i need to enable pty in php like ./configure --enable-pty. But the php is installed as part of lampp. I could not configure php.

How can I enable pty using pear. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recompile PHP, which is nothing PEAR can help you with.